# Issue with evaluating ' regexp ' for '\c+' , ' \i\c* ' and ' [\i-[:]][\c-[:]]* '

Tags: regex, user-interface, xsd, tcl, validation

I Am working on a TCL GUI, and I obtain the Data Tree structure for the GUI from a XML Schema, and I have to validate the entry fields fro the restrictions as in the XML Schema. In the XML Schema I am working with I have the simple types NMTOKEN Name and NCName with pattern restrictions '`\c+`' , '`\i\c*`' and '`[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*`' respectively.
The code i use to check is

```
method validatePatternValue { value } { 
    set patternCheck 1
    
    set pattern "^($patternValue)\$"
    set patternCheck [regexp $pattern $value]
    
    if {$patternCheck == 0} {
        tk_messageBox -message "Only Characters within range $patternValue for $patternValueType is\
                                accepted "
        return 0
    } 
   
    return 1
}
```

and whenever the $pattern is one of these '`\c+`' , '`\i\c*`' and '`[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*`' my text field does not accept any input and keeps throwing an error exception dialogue.

Just to add some more info, I came across this website, with some good info regarding my question about processing combinations of '`\i`' and '`\c`'. But is there no other way apart from the one suggested in the following link : [XML Schema Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#xml)

Comment: In this wordy question, the single most crucial thing is missing: the error message (and attaching the provided stack trace wouldn't hurt either). Please update your question accordingly. (The standard Tk error dialog allows you to save the error text along with the stack trace to a file.)

Comment: @kostix: Message was probably “`couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid escape \ sequence`”; either that or a simple failure to match anything expected (like would happen with `\c+`, which the 8.5 RE engine can at least compile to _something_, testing with `regexp -about`).

Comment: @kostix I am sorry if the question is too descriptive, i just did not want to miss out any detail and i guess i did screw up. As Mr.Fellows had pointed out the error message is " couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid escape \ sequence " I have found a temporary work around for now but any good solutions, suggestions are most welcome. Thank you very much Mr.Kostix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\c` escape sequence does not do in Tcl regexp what it does in XML-Schema regexp.

In [XML Schema](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#xml)

> `\c` matches any character that may occur after the first character in
> an XML name, i.e. `[-._:A-Za-z0-9]`

In Tcl

> `\cX` (where X is any character) the character whose low-order 5 bits
> are the same as those of X, and whose other bits are all zero

It's also clearly stated in the link you sent

> Note that the \c shorthand syntax conflicts with the control character
> syntax used in many other regex flavors.

You should try using `[-.:\w]` instead of `\c`

The same is true for `\i`, it's not doing the same in Tcl and in XML

Comment: Also, `[\i-[:]]` will definitely do something completely different in Tcl's RE engine (or any other that is even vaguely POSIX-compliant) to what the XML Schema specification states. Bad schema specification! Naughty! No biscuit!

Comment: And the worst part? Converting these forms to standard RE forms is itself quite non-trivial, beyond what a simple `string map` or `regsub` can do. Yuck!

Comment: @DonalFellows, I wonder if `tdom` could somehow be used to check an artifically constructed minimal XML document, in which the user-supplied value is embedded? Then, a regular schema validation could possibly be used. Appears to be immensely heavy-weight though...

Comment: @kostix I was just considering the transformation of the REs; the problem is that the transformation required depends on whether you're inside `[]` or not, and you're having to do (character) set subtraction to process the results (which could be done with a negative lookahead I suppose, but ewwww!)

Comment: @DonalFellows, as you said, it's a very bad schema they are using. I would think a manual replacement must be done. Poor NANDAGOPAL is going to have a lot of work.

Comment: @Nir Levy Yeah I am having a lot work with lreplace, lindex, regsub and a never ending list of conversions and substitutions. XML Schema is tough work! and as you had suggested i did end up substituting [-._:A-Za-z0-9] in the place of \c wherever \c appears, seems to do the job for the moment